# Gnome file explorer window opens in the background instead of foreground

Tags: 20.04, gnome, appimage

With some applications, when I use some sort of "open file" or "save file" IO function, the file manager window will open behind the caller application window instead of the foreground, forcing me to click around.

When it opens in the background, I usually get a notification that the file manager window is "ready" (see screenshot).

How can I make it so file explorer windows called by applications are always opened in the foreground?

[image: example background open notification]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In default Gnome Shell, windows indeed are not automatically brought into focus. A notification instead appears when the window has become available.

In Gnome 20.04, install the system extension `gnome-shell-extension-no-annoyance` (preferred). Alternatively, install the extension "No annoyance" from the Gnome Shell extensions website.

In later versions of Ubuntu, this functionality is included and activated by default in the extension "Ubuntu Dock".

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- it might be a bit too brief to understand how to fix it.

Comment: For newer versions of Ubuntu/Gnome you need to use https://github.com/bdaase/noannoyance which is a maintained fork of the original. Installation instructions on the website. Note, to get Gnome Shell extensions to be come available you have to restart Gnome Shell by Alt-F2, then issue the `r` command.